# Is it possible to add lot size calculator inside short and long position in tradingview?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I want to add a system that calculate the lot size automatically according to the account balance, risk %, and price levels (entry price and stop level)
[image]

In the actual tool ( image above) I have to enter the lot size manually which is not quit productive, I have to open other lot size calculator app and copy the price level there.
How can I add code to compute the the lot size automatically using pine script?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate your lot size how you would normally do based on your entry price, stop loss price, risk and equity. Then you can use the `qty` argument of `strategy.entry()` and specify your lot size there.

> ***qty (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Number of
> contracts/shares/lots/units to trade. The default value is 'NaN'.